# Integral equation for Probability that A realizes before B AND B realizes before C

Tags: probability

$A$: random variable to denote time to failure for equipment E_A

$B$: random variable to denote time to failure for equipment E_B

$A$ and $B$ are independent.

$P(A◁B)(T)$ : Probability that A realizes **before** B in time range (0, T).

I know & understand the equation below (from a paper):

$$P(A◁B)(T)=\int_0^T \biggl( pdf_A(t)*(1-CDF_B(t)) \biggr) dt$$

I couldn't figure the integral structure for the case that there exists 3rd random variable:

$C$: random variable to denote time to failure for equipment E_C

$A$ and $B$ and $C$ are independent.

$P(A◁B◁C)(T)$ : Probability that A realizes **before** B AND B realizes **before** C in time range (0, T).

$$P(A◁B◁C)(T)=INTEGRAL\ STRUCTURE$$

**What is the INTEGRAL STRUCTURE in this 3 variable case?**

Do i need a double integral something or does my trial below correct?

$$P(A◁B◁C)(T)=\int_0^T \biggl( pdf_A(t)*(1-CDF_B(t)) \biggr) dt \times \int_0^T \biggl( pdf_B(t)*(1-CDF_C(t)) \biggr) dt$$

thanks. regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous about which variables occur prior to time $T$ in the three variable case.  Based on your comment below, the event of interest is that all three events occur by time $T$ and they occur in the stated order:

$$\{A ◁ B ◁ C\}(T) \quad \quad \iff \quad \quad 
A < B < C \leqslant T.$$

Assuming that $A,B,C$ are mutually independent non-negative random variables, and using your notation for the events of interest (but standard notation for the PDFs and CDFs) you would have:

$$\mathbb{P}(A ◁ B ◁ C)(T) = \int \limits_0^T \Bigg( \int \limits_a^T p_B(b) (F_C(T)-F_C(b)) \ db \Bigg) p_A(a) \ da.$$

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for help. All 3 variables occur: **(A & B & C occur in time range (0,T)) & (A before B) & (B before C)**. After my this comment does the integral need to be updated? **May you update it pls if required?**Also, I couldn't understand $\int_a$. I only have 1 time range that is** $(0,T1)$

Comment: Okay, I've updated the integral to incorporate this new information.